# Use batch script to copy directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to copy a folder to the same directory and change its name. Let's say, if I have a folder "C:\Users\Desktop\A", how can I copy it, rename it as "B", and still put it at "C:\Users\Desktop"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xcopy "C:\Users\Desktop\A" "C:\Users\Desktop\B" /e /i
```

Comment: Besides, do you have some good batch coding tutorial to recommend? I am very new to this.

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt

```
xcopy source target /E
```

`/E` recursivly copies files and directories.

So:

```
xcopy c:\users\Desktop\A c:\users\Desktop\B /E
```

Comment: Do you know how can I use "Relative path"? Let's say my current path is "c:\users\desktop", if I use".\A" and ".\B", it doesn't work.

Comment: got it. Use back slash will do.